# Stuck on sudo apt-get update

Tags: 16.04, apt, sudo

On Ubuntu 16.04 I'm stuck with this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::14)]
```

Comment: try to disable IPv6, then try to update again.

Comment: its work after disabling